# Getting the right focus with the self timer on a Nikon D5600

Tags: nikon, dslr, nikon-d5600

I recently upgraded from a Nikon D5200 to a Nikon D5600.  I'm trying to take self portraits with the self-timer setting on the 5600 but I'm struggling to get the right focus.  With the 5200 I had a remote but unfortunately the 5600 doesn't have a remote capability so I'll hit the button, but then if I go to far away, I'm out of focus and my photo ends up blurry.  I don't want to use the snap bridge app because I don't want my phone in every photo.  The app only allows for a 2 second self timer but that doesn't really give you enough time to push the button and get into a pose.

I'm feeling really frustrated and I don't know what to do.  I'm a blogger and I need to take good quality photos and I'm feeling defeated with this new camera.  Help!

Answer (score 1):

I'd avoid relying on any remote or automatic functionality - go full manual, especially focus. Switch off AF on the lens and/or camera body to be certain.

Put something where you're intending to be - if you're halfway across a field, stick a bamboo pole or similar in the ground and focus on that. Set up your aperture and shutter, which might be different with a fake subject so bracket if possible. When you've set the self timer running and get to the stick, stand just in front of it or throw it out of the shot.

I've always wanted a question I could answer with the words "a pointed stick". And I was able to say "go full manual" too. You've made my day.

Answer (score 1):

What do you mean by "doesn't have remote capability"? You can either use Snapbridge, MC-DC2 remote cord or WR-1/WR-T10/WR-R10 wireless transmitters and receivers to control your camera remotely.

There's really no need to fiddle with manual focusing and other funky stuff. Nikon removed only the infrared option.

Comment: Perfect juxtaposition. I'm off to get popcorn. But how do you hold a violin and a camera at the same time?